# is it possible to increase the price when the user renew the subscription in stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I have my application in ruby on rails 5 and I am using stripe for membership fees, my idea is to establish a price to the plan or membership of 5 usd weekly and if the user does not cancel on time, when he will renew the membership you will be charged 8 usd at the time of payment. is it possible to do it with stripe? stripe have any option to renew? What options do I have to develop this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to charge user 5 dollars per week as a trial and they could choose to renew or auto-renew but the renewing price is 8 dollars per week going forward? 
There are many ways to do it. One way to do is 
1. create product called memebership 
2. create a plan out of the product with billing cycle of 1 week and price of 8 dollars 
3. create a coupon discounting 3 dollars for one time 
4. Subscribe the customer to the plan created at step 2 with coupon created at step 3
5. The subscription will auto renew at the end unless user/you explicitly cancel it

Comment: refer to https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts for discount
refer to https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment to see how to model your billing